# Update junction in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, symbolic-link, junction

I'm doing this:

```
net stop wuauserv
```

then:

rename c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old

and then:

```
mklink E:\windows\SoftwareDistribution \D
```

I'm doing `\d` in the end because otherwise it doesn't work and \d because of the same reason.

and then:

```
mklink /J C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution "E:\windows\SoftwareDistribution
```

so then I try to

```
net start wuauserv
```

and I get this message:

```
C:\Windows\system32>NET START WUAUSERV
The Windows Update service is starting.
The Windows Update service could not be started.

A system error has occurred. 

System error 3 has occurred.

The system cannot find the path specified.
```

So what am I doing wrong? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### So what am I doing wrong?

> I'm doing this:
>
> ```
> net stop wuauserv
> ```
>
> then:
>
> ```
> rename c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
> ```
>
> and then:
>
> ```
> mklink E:\windows\SoftwareDistribution \D
> ```

This command will create a directory symbolic link to the directory `\D` (if it exists). I don't think this is what you want to do.

> I'm doing \d in the end because otherwise it doesn't work and \d
>   because of the same reason.
>
> and then:
>
> ```
> mklink /J C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution "E:\windows\SoftwareDistribution
> ```

The previous command has a mismatch `"` character. It should be:

```
mklink /J C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution "E:\windows\SoftwareDistribution"
```

or:

```
mklink /J C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution E:\windows\SoftwareDistribution
```

Note:

`E:\windows\SoftwareDistribution` must already exist for this to work.

---

#### The correct approach

Use the following commands:

```
net stop wuauserv
rename c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution c:\windows\softwaredistribution.old
md E:\windows\SoftwareDistribution
mklink /J C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution E:\windows\SoftwareDistribution
net start wuauserv
```

---

Source [Redirecting Updates and the Software Distribution Folder using Junction to another hard drive](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jeffloucks/2010/09/19/redirecting-updates-and-the-software-distribution-folder-using-junction-to-another-hard-drive/)

Comment: well i try it , and i get the same resullts as before.

Comment: and i got a question why did i dont need symbolic link ins't it his point be symbolic to direct the c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution to hes new destination

Comment: anyway  i get the same results as before without success

Comment: @Anonymous Did you create the directory `E:\windows\SoftwareDistribution` first? See updated answer.

Comment: thank you man, well i just realized it wrong from the beggining i assumed the symbolic link is the key,you know to direct the SoftwareDistribution from c to the symbolic in E .